# Main.java is not on the classpath of project NewProject_880753af, only syntax errors are reported - Java(32)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Yesterday I opened VS Code after a month or so, and I noticed, that all my projects' Java files can't run. I see a light blue curved underline under the first letter in all my Java files, which says:

`Main.java is not on the classpath of project NewProject_880753af, only syntax errors are reported - Java(32)`

I have my Java file inside "src" directory inside my project directory "NewProject".

When I try to run my file, it then prompts me to add the parent folder to some Java source path:

`The file Main.java isn't on the classpath, the runtime may throw class not found error. Do you want to add the parent folder "NewProject/src" to Java source path?`

Then it gives me two options - "Add to Source Path" or "Skip". If I press "Skip", it shows an error again:

`Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json.`

If I choose "Add to Source Path", then it creates a folder called ".vscode" with a file "settings.json" in which there's the following code:

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

And after that it works... but... I just don't understand - why did Visual Studio Code fail to run my file even if it was working everytime I ran it in the past and without any prompts to add my parent folder to source path or anything?? And I didn't need any "launch.json" files!

How can I fix this problem without creating any new folders inside my project directory?

Comment: Was there any updates or something?

Comment: Yeshwin Verma The Programmer, yes, in that month of not using VS Code I'm sure there were some updates, that are now installed for my VS Code.

Comment: I think the problem happened with that update

Comment: Do you think I should use the earlier version of VS Code and never update it?

Comment: Besides the folder `src`, is there any other sub-fonlders in your parent folder?

Comment: In this project - no. But in projects with some more subfolders it fails too.

Comment: Before you trigger `Add to Source Path` which generates `.vscode/settings.json`, have you ever set anything in your settings.json file? like the 'java.project.sourcePaths'

Comment: I don't have any `settings.json` file inside my project directory. Everything worked fine until now without any "launch.json" or "settings.json" in my project directory. However, when I open global VSCode settings, a file "settings.json" opens, and there I don't have "java.project.sourcePaths".

Comment: View [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) first to learn about their differences. `launch.json` is generated for debugging. The configuration to current openend project would be stored in `settings.json` and `launch.json`, which located in folder **.vscode**. So that's why `"java.project.sourcePaths"` doesn't exist in global Settings. **.vscode** is created automactically if vscode detects you've done some configurations.